# Sublime Text tab closes auto-complete window

Tags: autocomplete, tabs, sublimetext

I hope it's a short question.

When I start typing in Sublime Text 2/3 the auto-completion window appears. If I press `tab` I start cycling through the options I have which is exactly what I want. However, at the same time as soon as I have pressed `tab` the auto-completion popup closes.

Is there some option to make the popup stay alive, showing me the item I am currently at. (the same behavior as with a `down` key). So I would like to achieve something in between the `down` key and `tab` key behavior.

Hope I have described the issue precise enough. If something is not clear - I will be happy to provide more details.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand the behavior you're looking for but these are the available completion settings in `Preferences.sublime-settings`:

```
{   
    // When enabled, pressing tab will insert the best matching completion.
    // When disabled, tab will only trigger snippets or insert a tab.
    // Shift+tab can be used to insert an explicit tab when tab_completion is
    // enabled.
    "tab_completion": true,

    // Enable auto complete to be triggered automatically when typing.
    "auto_complete": true,

    // The maximum file size where auto complete will be automatically triggered.
    "auto_complete_size_limit": 4194304,

    // The delay, in ms, before the auto complete window is shown after typing
    "auto_complete_delay": 50,

    // Controls what scopes auto complete will be triggered in
    "auto_complete_selector": "source - comment",

    // Additional situations to trigger auto complete
    "auto_complete_triggers": [ {"selector": "text.html", "characters": "<"} ],

    // By default, auto complete will commit the current completion on enter.
    // This setting can be used to make it complete on tab instead.
    // Completing on tab is generally a superior option, as it removes
    // ambiguity between committing the completion and inserting a newline.
    "auto_complete_commit_on_tab": false,

    // Controls if auto complete is shown when snippet fields are active.
    // Only relevant if auto_complete_commit_on_tab is true.
    "auto_complete_with_fields": false
}
```

You may be able to get the behavior you desire by customizing them.

Comment: Hey @inkdeep, thanks for the answer, but I have, of course, already played with the settings there. I am not able to achieve the needed behavior. Therefore I have posted this question in case someone had the same thought as me before.

Answer (score 1):

if you use AutoSave plugin, it will be the cause of fast-closing popup window. Try to disable this extension.

Answer (score 0):

### Override the Tab Key Binding

I found the following to provide the solution.  It just invokes the auto complete again, resulting in the next option to be selected.

```
{ "keys": ["tab"], 
    "command": "auto_complete",
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "auto_complete_visible" },
        { "key": "setting.auto_complete_commit_on_tab", "operand": false }
    ]
}
```

**Remember to add a comma if this isn't your only key binding.**

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue- found this solution in their forums:

Add this to your keymap file:

```
{ "keys": ["tab"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\t"}, "context":
   [
      { "key": "auto_complete_visible" },
      { "key": "setting.tab_completion", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
   ]
}
```

Comment: This just inserts a new tab. It doesn't cycle through auto-completion options.